# rbenv local using 2.1.3 but ruby -v shows 2.0.0 and wont run rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I am using rbenv and as far as I know I have it installed correctly. I have installed 2.1.3 with rbenv and have run "rbenv local 2.1.3".

rbenv versions shows
  system
* 2.1.3 (set by /Users/myusername/desktop/foldername/.ruby-version)
  2.1.4

When I run rbenv local, I get 2.1.3

However, when I try to run rails s, I get the error, "Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.3"

What am I doing wrong? I have tried rehashing. How do I get rails to recognize that I'm running 2.1.3?

**edit:** 
I just added

```
PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

into my ~/.bash_profile. Now when I do ruby -v it correctly states 2.1.3. When I change local or global, ruby -v changes accordingly. However, when I try to run rails s, I still get the error

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.3
```

**edit 2:**
apparently I just needed to close and open a new terminal window. -.-
Problem solved.

Comment: Please post the output of these two commands: `command -v ruby` and `bundle exec rails server`

Comment: command -v ruby:
/usr/bin/ruby

bundle exec rails server
Could not find nokogiri-1.6.4.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.